# Sending App-generated Requests to all users of an app

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-canvas, apprequests

Is it possible to send an app-generated notification request to all users of a canvas app? I'm currently sending requests to individual users, but not the entire user base. I do not want to simply loop over all users and send an individual request to each. Furthermore, that seems SPAMish. In fact the whole concept seems SPAMish, so I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is simply, 'No, Facebook won't let you do that.'

Comment: Eric, can you please share the code you used to send the requests? I mean with the loop.

Comment: Tony, I never built a loop like what I described. Contacting users in this manner violates Facebook's TOS. The best--and accepted--method for contacting users is to post to your App Fan Page's stream. Since I asked this question, Facebook creates and associates a Fan Page with each App that you create. When you post in the App's stream, it will appear in each user's News Feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send to 20 users at a time with [batch requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

Comment: That's not true see: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/ **example of an app-generated request**. This allows you to send an app generated request to an individual user, which I have implemented. What I'm wondering is if you can send a request to all users, not just an individual. For example, to notify them that the rules have changed or something like that.

Comment: Sorry you're right I forgot about that post.  They haven't updated the other documentation to reflect that.  I doubt they will provide a way to mass-spam everyone.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer, under the assumption of 'No, Facebook won't let you do that.'